# Could not load the Qt platform plugin (while dockerizing the application)

Tags: python, docker, qt, opencv, face-recognition

I have built a face detection app using opencv and transfer learning model (resnetSSD).
Output of application  : video will open and model will be able to recognize the faces.

Application is running perfectly in my local system .. Able to build the docker also , but when running the docker container below error i am getting:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

please suggest how i can fix this ??

Comment: I has the same problem without docker - but I don't remeber what I made to solve it. I'm not sure if I reinstalled `cv2` or I installed newer `PyQt5` or helped to install `PyQt6`

Answer (score 0):

To show images from inside Docker container you should run it like below:

```
docker run -it \
   -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \                # <--- here
   -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \   # <--- Here
# everyting else
```

After making sure `cv2` is properly installed in docker image you may wish to run

```
xhost +local:root
```

on the host machine (assuming it's a local experiment).